# bash, use array with * in it

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm working on a small script that loads some iptables lists and writes each line to a associated chain-file.
This all works only if the script runs in an empty directory.
As far as I understand correctly, this is due to the array in which I have the value * stored. As soon as a line with * is called, the value is replaced with all files in the current directory.

Do you guys know a simple solution to run the script in a non-empty folder?

here is an example of output when the script runs in ~

```
LOG tcp -- Bilder Dokumente Downloads Musik Öffentlich Schreibtisch Videos Vorlagen eth1 !125.238.212.131 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:45 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `LOGSMTP '
LOG tcp -- Bilder Dokumente Downloads Musik Öffentlich Schreibtisch Videos Vorlagen eth1 !125.238.212.131 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:225 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `LOGSMTP '
```

and here is an example of the output when it runs in an empty folder
(it should look like this)

```
LOG tcp -- * eth1 !125.238.212.131 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:45 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `LOGSMTP '
LOG tcp -- * eth1 !125.238.212.131 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:225 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `LOGSMTP '
```

and here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /scripts/s.iptables.d/work
data=$(ls /scripts/s.iptables.d/iptables*)

for file in $data
do
        outputpath="/output/s.iptables-"
        while read -r line
        do
                arr=($line)
                case "$line" in
                        Chain* )        chain=${arr[1]}
                                        output=$outputpath$chain
                                        inactiveoutput=$outputpath$chain"-inactive"
                                        ;;
                        [1-9]* )        reg="^[0-9]*\s+0\s+0.*$"
                                        if [[ "$line" =~ "$reg" ]]
                                        then
                                        echo "${arr[@]:3}" >> $inactiveoutput
                                        else
                                        echo "${arr[@]:3}" >> $output
                                        fi
                                        ;;
                esac
        done < <(cat "$file")
done
```

I am looking forward to any help and thank you in advance

Comment: Escape it with a backslash, you know, `\*`, and test it

Comment: So if I escape every `*`, I would have to replace every `\*` before it can be written. This would, substantially increase the running time. Do you have a other idea?

Comment: Have you tried using backticks ( ` ) around the ls command instead of using the $() notation? So would look like data=` ls /scripts/s.iptables.d/iptables* `

Answer (score 1):

Don't parse `ls` -> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Do one of these:

```
files=( /scripts/s.iptables.d/iptables* )
for file in "${files[@]}"
```

or simply

```
for file in /scripts/s.iptables.d/iptables*
```

Also `done < <(cat "$file")` is an excessive use of process substitution, just use

```
done < "$file"
```